# SwiftUI: Four views of the same type all show as different sizes

Tags: ios, swiftui, scale, frame

I am creating an app that will let people keep score in board games.  I created a view that contains the player name and their current score.  I have my iphone layout set to landscape and don't care which layout is used on the ipad.  The problem I am having is when I am on my iphone the size of the four player views are all different.  You can see that I am trying to use .frames, and I assumed swiftUI would realize the four views should always remain the same size.  This solution might not be optimal, but I am trying to figure out how to fit it all on the page and have it scale to fit within an ipad view?

Here is the current view:
Player 1 in the top right corner or player two in the bottom left would be great sizes

[image]

**Player View:**

```
struct PlayerView: View {
var playerName:String
//var score:Int
var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3)
            .frame(minWidth: 115, idealWidth: 115, maxWidth: 384, minHeight: 25, idealHeight: 34, maxHeight: 50, alignment: .center)
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10)
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(minWidth: 115, idealWidth: 115, maxWidth: 384, minHeight: 25, idealHeight: 34, maxHeight: 50, alignment: .center)
        Text("\(playerName)")
            .foregroundColor(.white)

    }
```

**Score View:**

```
struct ScoreView: View {

var body: some View {

    ZStack(alignment:.bottom){
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .stroke(Color.black, lineWidth: 3)
                .frame(minWidth: 115, idealWidth: 115, maxWidth: 200, minHeight: 100, idealHeight: 100, maxHeight: 175, alignment: .center)

        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
            .fill(Color.blue)
            .frame(minWidth: 115, idealWidth: 115, maxWidth: 200, minHeight: 100, idealHeight: 100, maxHeight: 175, alignment: .center)
        VStack(spacing: 3){
        Text("Points")
        Text("0")
            .padding(.bottom)
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
    }
    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

}
```

}

**Combined View:**

```
struct ScoreBoardView: View {
var playerName: String
var body: some View {

    ZStack(alignment: .top){
        ScoreView()
            .layoutPriority(2.0)
        PlayerView(playerName: playerName)
            .layoutPriority(1.0)
        }


}
```

}

**Board View:**

```
 var body: some View {

    VStack {
        Text("BANNER PLACEHOLDER")
            .padding([.leading,.trailing],80)
            .padding([.top,.bottom],20)
            .border(Color.black)
        HStack {

            VStack{
                ScoreBoardView(playerName: "Player 1")
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)
                    .padding(.leading,10)

                ScoreBoardView(playerName: "Player 2")
                    .padding(.leading,10)


            }

            addPointsCombinedView()
                .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                .layoutPriority(1.0)

            VStack{
                ScoreBoardView(playerName: "Player 3")
                    .padding(.bottom, 50)

                ScoreBoardView(playerName: "Player 4")

            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: Many hardcoded parameters, use instead relative & calculated.

Comment: Could you add your `addPointsCombinedView` so that it is a [mcve]?  I think you will be able to fix your problem by adding a `Spacer()` between each of the top and bottom score boards. Essentially you need somewhere for the extra space to go so that the scoreboard vstack is the same height as the add points view

Comment: @Asperi I want to make my code better.  Can you give me an example of how to use relative & calculated parameters for this solution?

Answer (score 0):

It finally clicked last night. I was able to solve the problem by putting my combined view into HStacks and then imbedding those into VStacks.  It looks much nicer now.

```
VStack {
    Text("BANNER PLACEHOLDER")
        .padding([.leading,.trailing],80)
        .padding([.top,.bottom],10)
        .border(Color.black)
        .padding(.top, 5)
        .layoutPriority(1.0)

ZStack{
        addPointsCombinedView()
            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)

    VStack {


        HStack {
            ScoreBoardView(playerName: "Player 1")
                .padding(.leading, 20)
                .padding(.bottom, 7)
                .padding(.top,5)
            Spacer()
            ScoreBoardView(playerName: "Player 2")
                .padding(.trailing, 20)
                .padding(.bottom, 7)
                .padding(.top,5)
        }

        HStack{
                ScoreBoardView(playerName: "Player 3")
                    .padding(.leading, 20)
                    .padding(.top,10)
                    .padding(.bottom,5)
                Spacer()
                ScoreBoardView(playerName: "Player 4")
                    .padding(.trailing,20)
                    .padding(.top,10)
                    .padding(.bottom,5)

           }

        }

    }
}
}
```

}